# How to iterate through RecyclerView and inflate different row using method `getItemViewType()`?

Tags: android

I have one list where i'm showing some statuses and now i want to show after every 5 element in list some different view, but i can't achieve that. Probably i should use loop for this, but i have tried and made some mistake. For now i got view type just for element in the middle of list, but that is not i want. I would like to show that view after every 5 element. This is how my code looks:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (jokes.get(position) != null) {
        if (position % 5 == 0 && position != 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_BANNER;
        }
        return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    } else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return jokes == null ? 0 : jokes.size();
}
```

Comment: Classic case for using the modulo operator, right? `if(position % 5 == 0) return VIEW_TYPE_BANNER;`

Comment: That is it, but why it is loading also view at first position?

Comment: 0 % 5 ist also 0. So you need to filter the first position. e.g. `if(position != 0 && position % 5 == 0)`

Comment: You will also need to adjust for positions not matching joke index since you fill some positions with banner. Like joke number 5 will be showm at position 6.

Comment: Yes i can see. I'm not getting last element from jokes array.

Comment: @totoro is right. This is why I wouldn't recommend to determine the viewtype by the position. Rather use a generic dataset and help yourself with `instaceof`if-clauses

Comment: Also getItemCount() should return the length of jokes + number of banners.

Comment: How would i determine how many banners are there? My `getItemCount()` is now returning `jokes.size()` if jokes is not null.

Comment: If you put a banner every five positions the number of banners to use is (length of jokes - 1) / 5. If you don't want a banner at the end of lets say 15 jokes. Otherwise you can just do length of jokes / 5. Integer math, not float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Change

```
return jokes == null ? 0 : jokes.size();
```

to

```
return jokes == null ? 0 : jokes.size() + jokes.size() / 5;
```

to reflect that you have more views because of banners, or

```
return jokes == null ? 0 : jokes.size() + (jokes.size() - 1) / 5;
```

if you don't put a banner at the end on let us say 15 jokes.

**Alternate solution**

Create an alternate `array` of `List<Object>` to use with the adapter.

Add `class Joke` where you want a joke and a `class Banner` where you want a banner.

Then in `getItemViewType(int position)` check the `array[position] instanceof` and return a value accordingly.

That way no math is needed.

Comment: Well at this moment i can't go with two classes. Everything is working fine with solutions from you and reVerse, just i'm not getting the last item from list, instead of that item, i'm getting Banner.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Updated with one proposal, though I think you have to look into `createViewHolder` as well.

Comment: i'm getting this error with applying your updated code:

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size is 16

Comment: How long is jokes?

Comment: I'm fetching 16 records into list.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic You problem is now in `createViewHolder` on position 5 you return a banner, and on position 6 you should return jokes.get(5) not jokes.get(6), do you follow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110934/discussion-between-dusan-dimitrijevic-and-totoro).

Comment: I'm getting an error in `getItemViewType()` method here: if (jokes.get(position) != null) The error is the same: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size is 16`